# Edit a text file using a Bash script

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have file which is of the following format:

```
axel localhost> localhost>
mike localhost> STORAGE 298390/512000 (58.279296875%) localhost>
ab localhost> STORAGE 141361/512000 (27.6095703125%) localhost>
fghi localhost> localhost>
abcd localhost> STORAGE 165929/512000 (32.4080078125%) localhost>
lmno localhost> STORAGE 353073/512000 (68.9595703125%) localhost>
nuon localhost> localhost>
spar localhost> STORAGE 203766/512000 (39.798046875%) localhost>
fibo localhost> STORAGE 238204/512000 (46.52421875%) localhost>
nacci localhost> STORAGE 425737/512000 (83.1517578125%) localhost>
seldom localhost> STORAGE 69894/512000 (13.651171875%) localhost>
project localhost> STORAGE 86220/512000 (16.83984375%) localhost>
eccleston localhost> STORAGE 240084/512000 (46.89140625%) localhost>
swan localhost> STORAGE 279522/512000 (54.594140625%) localhost>
```

This is the output generated by `listquota` in cyradm (Cyrus-imapd). I have two questions;

- In those lines which have `localhost> localhost>`, the first word should be written into another file and that line should be deleted.
- For the other lines, the second, third and last columns need to be deleted.

How would I go about achieving this result?

**Edit**

*Expected output*

```
mike 298390/512000 (58.279296875%)
ab 141361/512000 (27.6095703125%)
abcd 165929/512000 (32.4080078125%)
lmno 353073/512000 (68.9595703125%)
spar 203766/512000 (39.798046875%)
fibo 238204/512000 (46.52421875%)
nacci STORAGE 425737/512000 (83.1517578125%)
```

My loop so far looks something like:

```
while read thisline; do
    if [ $2 == "localhost>" AND $3 == "localhost>" ];then
        echo $1 >>/root/names.txt
        sed '1d' filename.txt #but this deletes only the first line
    fi

done
```

Comment: So the expected output is...? And what have been your attempts so we can help you improve them?

Comment: @fedorqui - Sorry, edited question.

Comment: you are using `$2` and `$3` as awk would do, but it's not correct here. You should store these values and then check its content. Then the `sed` part should be deleting with `sed '$line d' and keep increasing `$line`. Anyway, I think Kent's answer goes very fast to the point so I would use that.

Comment: Almost every time you write a loop in a shell script you have the wrong approach. Most good shell solutions are a series of pipes. Loops usually are best implemented in awk, perl, etc. Also, shell is not an appropriate language for parsing text files - that's what awk was invented for and so is very good at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
awk '/localhost> localhost>/{print $1 >"file2";next}{$2=$3=$NF=""}7' file
```

this will output text you want, and generate a "file2" for the `localhost> localhost>` case.

didn't test, I hope there is no typoes.

Comment: what's the last 7 for?

Comment: @i.h4d35 you can use any number except `0` . I used 7 because I like 7.

Comment: @Kent What does the number do?

Comment: @Bernhard awk will do print if there is a True value. so it lets awk print the whole (modified) line.

Comment: Nevermind, I get it, it is too easy :), if you only would have written `};7` :)

Comment: @Kent - Got it to work. Saved the whole cyrus result in a file and the `cat filename | awk '/localhost> localhost>/{print $1 >"file2";next}{$2=$3=$NF=""}'`. Thanks for this. I never knew you could loop through a file using awk - gotta rewrite some of my bash scripts now.....

Comment: @fedorqui - Thanks for the reference guide. Quite useful

Comment: @i.h4d35 glad to help. btw, you don't need `cat file|awk '..code..'` the cat is useless. just `awk '..codes..' file`